# VMWare Workstation 9: Assigning ip in Windows Server 2008 breaks internet connection

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a host running VMWare Workstation 9 with the following things:

Network:
VMnet8 (NAT)
SubnetIP: 192.168.10.0
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.10.100
DHCP enabled
IP Range: 101-110

1 Virtual Machine:
OS: Windows Server 2008 Enterprise
VMWare Tools installed
ipconfig: IP 192.168.10.101; mask fine; gateway fine

My problem:
When the machine boots up I can connect to the internet.
But as soon as I change the IP in ipv4 properties to:
192.168.10.101
255.255.255.0
192.168.10.100
and DNS:
192.168.10.101 (I want to use it as DNS server)
My internet connection stops and the Network is "Local only"

Are any of my properties wrong?
I'm following one of trainsignals tutorials with this.

Comment: checked your firewall both in host and guest?

Comment: well, i connects to the internet just fine until I change the ipv4 properties. I disabled it anyways, but it didn't work.

Comment: What system has the 192.168.10.101 IP? And what IP settings do you have exactly when the internet still works?

Comment: What do you mean with system? As to the settings: IP: 192.168.10.101 Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.10.100

Comment: Do you actually have a DNS setup at .101?  When it's 'not working' can you access sites by IP address?